# How to code a function to print 'equal' if two integers are equal and if not, it will not print anything?

Tags: python, function

I am defining a function called is_equal. If the two numbers are equal, the code prints 'equal'. If they do not match, it prints nothing. The numbers are hard-coded in; so there is no input from the keyboard. I have tried moving the 'print(equal) underneath the def is_equal, but it still doesn't print anything; although the numbers match. Any suggestions?

```
def is_equal(num1, num2):
    if num == 4:
        num1 = int(num1)
        num2 = int(num2)
        is_equal(4,4)
        print(equal)
```

``

Comment: Where is `num` defined?

Comment: All you need is: `if int(num1) == int(num2):` and then your `print()` statement. Not sure why you have everything else. Then call it with something like `is_equal(4, 4)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do,

```
def is_equal(num1, num2):
    if int(num1) == int(num2):
        print("Numbers are equal")
```

Anything you put under the `if` condition will be executed when the numbers (`num1` and `num2`) have same value.
The other things in your function doesn't make sense. You can remove them as they are not required for the task you have mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that 'equal' is an undeclared variable? The 'equal' in the print statement is missing quotation marks, if it was supposed to be a string.

Comment: Thanks, Buddy. As you stated, I did forget to put the quotation marks around the 'equal'.